# stopwatch time per user in c# asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, stopwatch

I have a set of users in my asp.net mvc application.

When any user start stopwatch then i need stopwatch to continue  even after user logout. And run it  until he does not login again and click stop.

i can start it on start button click

```
        stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
```

**But how can i track it against user? so that after the user logout and then login he will see the elapsed time including the time he was not active in the app?**

so after the user login and click stop watch he should get the elapsed time including the whole time.

TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

**is it better to use angular directive/javascript timer?**

Comment: You can save the date & time user logged out and then after he login with a simple math, get the whole time.

Comment: thats a good option.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a `Stopwatch` for something like that?
`Stopwatch` is designed to provide high-resolution time measurements, I doubt your user needs to know the exact time down to a few nano-seconds...
[From MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Provides a set of methods and properties that you can use to accurately measure elapsed time.

Simply save the `DateTime.Now()`, the state of the button (i.e start, stop) and the user id, and then when the user with the same id press that button again just calculate the time differences.

```
TimeSpan elapsedTime = FirstClickDateTime - SecondClickDateTime;
```

Then all you have to do is [format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the display of the [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) object.

Comment: actually i am planning to show user the elapsed time continuously. if i do it the way you are saying then when user clicks stop i can show him the elapsed time but what about showing elapsed time continuously?

Comment: You mean to start a timer?

Comment: start a timer with already elapsed time and continuing the timer in client side i guess

Comment: I see. It has to be on client side, for sure. But it's been a very long time since my javascript days, so I'm not so sure how to write something like this in js. However, I'm sure you can find some built in timer that can start from a value other then zero (perhaps in jquery). if not, then just write one yourself. It should'nt be so hard.

Comment: i think i have got my answer. in client sider using angularjs timer i can show the elapsed time to user and in server side i can do it as per your answer